# Send a push notification from java android studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im calling sendToToken("token") with a valid token of my device and its not working, i dont get what im missing is not failing i debuged is sending it correctly but the notification just dosnt appear on the target device that has my app installed.

What im missing can anybody help me figuring out? Me and my partner have been struggling with this for weeks

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package com.example.intercambiolibros.fragments;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {
        super.onMessageReceived(message);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                .setContentTitle(message.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(message.getNotification().getBody())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

class where im sending the notifications:

```
package com.example.intercambiolibros.fragments;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.intercambiolibros.R;
import com.example.intercambiolibros.activitys.LoginActivity;
import com.example.intercambiolibros.models.Libros;
import com.example.intercambiolibros.support.Constantes;
import com.example.intercambiolibros.support.conversaciones.Conversacion;
import com.example.intercambiolibros.support.mensajes.MensajeEnviar;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.*;


import org.ocpsoft.prettytime.PrettyTime;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;


public class LibrosInicioShow extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private BookAdapter bookAdapter;

    private EditText searchEditText;
    private List<Libros> bookList;

    private List<Libros> allBooks;


    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void setMode(String mode) {
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    private String mode = "";

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    private void setFCMToken() {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference usersRef = database.getReference("users");
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

// Get the device token for the current user
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("FCM", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());

                        }

                        // Get the device token from the task result
                        String token = task.getResult();

                        // Save the device token to the database for the current user
                        usersRef.child(userId).child("deviceToken").setValue(token);

                    }
                });

    }
    private RemoteMessage getMessage() {
        final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", "From DesertSync");
        map.put("xfrom", "Prueba");

        return new RemoteMessage.Builder("internal").setData(map).build();
    }

    public void sendToToken(String token) {
        // [START send_to_token]
        // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.



        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(
                new RemoteMessage.Builder(token + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                        .setMessageId("" + System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .addData("msg", "ping")
                        .addData("ts", "" + System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .build());
        // Response is a message ID string.
        // [END send_to_token]
    }
```

Build.gradle Module:app

```
  plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}


android {
    namespace 'com.example.intercambiolibros'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.intercambiolibros"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
//   implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0' mala
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
//
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.2.0'
//    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common-ktx:20.2.0'

//
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'


    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'

    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:5.0.4.Final'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:18.0.2'

}
```

build.gradle Project

```
  buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()

            dependencies {

                // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

            }

        }
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false



}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

        android:name=".support.ColorDinamico"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IntercambioLibros"
        tools:targetApi="33">



        <activity android:name=".activitys.DashBoardActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activitys.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activitys.registro_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".support.MyFirebaseMessagingService2"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: there is no way to send a message through FCM directly from one device to another device. You will need to call FCM from a trusted environment to send a message *to* a device.

---

The [`send` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#send(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage)) that you call is documented as:

> Sends `message` upstream to your app server.

You'll want to have a look at this diagram from the [architectural overview](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture) to see what that means:

> [image]

When you call `send` the client send a message to FCM, which delivers it to your configured app server. It does **not** deliver the message to another device.

To send a message **to** a device, you'll want to read the documentation on [building send requests on your app server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message). There are examples both using the Firebase Admin SDKs for various platforms or calls to the REST API there. The most important thing to realize is that such calls must always comes from a trusted environment/app server, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or something like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Comment: Thanks for the docs really helpfull response , im sending it with go following all the example, app its telling me that message is sended sucesfully but its not appearing on my firebase messagin console as a new campaing, either on the device im sending it too.

Do i need to give any permission to specific device to be able to see the push notification?

Comment: There is no API to create campaigns, so messages sent through the API will indeed not show in the Firebase console. --- To help troubleshoot message deliver, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Answer (score 0):

about sending a notification from a device to another

using postman https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
there is way
u need to activated fcm in google cloud console
and a key

in boths devices must have the app
then could make a post request from one to other